# Picturebox duplicating value

Tags: c#, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a little program that starts taking pictures in the moment you click on a button. Also it can be ended earlier clicking another button.

The little bug that I am having is that I use a timer to process each time you go throw it since you hit the start button in a 1000ms interval, the problem comes when the first process finishes, the next process you start will duplicate the value of a progressbar x2 forever until you close the app.

```cs
namespace Fotos
{
    public partial class Fotos : Form
    {
        private static string Path = @"C:\Fotos\";
        //private static string Agua = @"C:\Marca de Agua\";
        private bool HayDispositivos, terminado;
        private string nombre;
        private int i = 0, j = 0, z = 0, eleccion;
        private FilterInfoCollection MisDispositivos;
        private VideoCaptureDevice miWebcam;
        private MagickImageCollection gif = new MagickImageCollection();

        public Fotos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        {
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
            {
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
                {
                    return codec;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        private void Creador()
        {
            CreacionGif cg = new CreacionGif(gif, nombre);
            cg.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void MarcaAgua(PictureBox picturebox1)
        {
            RectangleF angulo = new RectangleF(1350, 975, 535, 90); //rectf for My Text
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(picturebox1.Image))
            {
                //g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 2), 655, 460, 535, 90); 
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                g.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 32, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, angulo, sf);

                EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Encoder myEncoder =  Encoder.Quality;
                EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 30L);
                myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

                if (progressBar1.Value == 0)
                {
                    j = 0;
                }
                picturebox1.Image.Save(Path + textBoxNombreFoto.Text + "_" + i + ".jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
                gif.Add(Path + textBoxNombreFoto.Text + "_" + i + ".jpg");
                gif[j].AnimationDelay = 200;
                j++;

                g.Dispose();
                sf.Dispose();
                
                /*  using (Image image = pictureBox1.Image)
                    using (Image watermarkImage = Image.FromFile(Agua +"fecha.jpg"))
                    using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
                    using (TextureBrush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush(watermarkImage))
                    {
                        int x = (image.Width / 2 - watermarkImage.Width / 2);
                        int y = (image.Height / 2 - watermarkImage.Height / 2);
                        watermarkBrush.TranslateTransform(x, y);
                        imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width + 1, watermarkImage.Height)));
                        image.Save(Path + i +".jpg");*/
            }
        }

        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CargaDispositivos();
        }

        public void CargaDispositivos()
        {
            MisDispositivos = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            if (MisDispositivos.Count > 0)
            {
                HayDispositivos = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < MisDispositivos.Count; i++)
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(MisDispositivos[i].Name.ToString());
                comboBox1.Text = MisDispositivos[0].Name.ToString();
            }
            else HayDispositivos = false;
        }

        private void CerrarWebcam()
        {
            if (miWebcam != null && miWebcam.IsRunning)
            {
                miWebcam.SignalToStop();
                miWebcam = null;
            }
        } 
        private void Capturando(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if(terminado == false)
            {
                Bitmap Imagen = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                pictureBox1.Image = Imagen;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            CerrarWebcam();
        }
        private void foto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (miWebcam != null && miWebcam.IsRunning && (radioButton1.Checked == true || radioButton2.Checked == true) && textBoxNombreFoto.TextLength > 0)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Start();
                timer1.Interval = 1000;
                timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
                terminado = false;

                if(radioButton1.Checked == true)
                {
                    eleccion = 18;
                    progressBar1.Maximum = 1800;
                }
                else
                {
                    eleccion = 36;
                    progressBar1.Maximum = 3600;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor revisa que todos los campos estén rellenos");
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CerrarWebcam();
            int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            string nombreVideo = MisDispositivos[i].MonikerString;
            miWebcam = new VideoCaptureDevice(nombreVideo);
            miWebcam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Capturando);
            miWebcam.Start();
        }
        private void finFoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MarcaAgua(pictureBox1);
            terminado = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (progressBar1.Value % 30 == 0 && progressBar1.Value <= eleccion && terminado != true || progressBar1.Value == 0)
            {
                miWebcam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Capturando);
                MarcaAgua(pictureBox1);

                z++;
            }
            if (progressBar1.Value < eleccion && terminado != true)
            {
                progressBar1.Value++;
                i++;
            }
            textBoxTiempo.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();
            textBoxTiempo.Update();

            if ((terminado == true || progressBar1.Value >= eleccion) &&  i!=0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer1.Dispose();
                progressBar1.Dispose();
                progressBar1.Value = 0;

                nombre = textBoxNombreFoto.Text;
                Creador();

                i = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("Proceso Terminado con Éxito");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your question. Please remove as much code as possible without making the bug disappear. Create a copy of your project first. We call this a [mre]. It should e.g. be possible to remove the commented code. And potentially you can rename some methods to be English, so it's easier for us to understand what they shall do.

Comment: Don't use `g.Dispose();` when using it in a `using` block. It will call the Dispose method twice

Comment: Thank you for your advice @ThomasWeller I will next make that to perform better in coding and fix more issues.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen It have corrected it but it still does the same. Anyways thanks for the advice

Comment: I noticed this in you code: `progressBar1.Dispose(); progressBar1.Value = 0`. You shouldn't access disposed objects. I recommend creating a small simple application where you try to use/reuse the progressbar.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to improve my knowledge in c# and Windows Forms and I might have done bad programming decisions. I have putted away disposed objects. The problem I have it might be due to some redundant repetition on code or due to some error of that kind